# Raspberry Pi software configuration tool?

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, raspbian

A friend gave me a Raspberry Pi, and I'm trying to install [Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian) on it, but I really new at this, and I don't know how to do it.

When I turn on the Raspberry Pi, all I see is a menu:

```
Raspberry Pi Sofware Cnfiguration Tool

1 Expand Filesystem

2 Chose user Password

3 Enable Boot to desktop/Scratch

4 Internationalissation options

5 Enable Camera

6 Add to Rastrack

7 Overclock

8 Advance Options

9 About raspi-config
```

What should I do?

Is there a good tutorial that teach how to install Linux?

Comment: if you are stuck on the initial config, maybe you should start with Raspbian - it's based on Debian and optimized for the pi.
http://www.raspbian.org/
Or is there a specific reason you are looking at debian?

Comment: @BenBartle no, I;m just try to lear how to use the raspberry and doing research I found that "debian" was the easiest to install and use

Comment: Then yeah, go the Raspbian route (which it looks like you are from the answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are brand new to Raspberry Pi I would install the [NOOBS](https://github.com/raspberrypi/noobs) package. It will install Rasbian which is built off of Debian.

- Start at http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/
- Next follow the video instruction tutorial on the setup, http://www.raspberrypi.org/help/noobs-setup/.

Comment: I will try this, thnk you